# Time Synchronization for distributed sensors

Tags: synchronization, sensors, distributed-computing, ntp, distributed-system

Each sensor connects to a mobile via bluetooth, then all the mobiles are connected with a host mobile also through bluetooth(see below pic). I  need to synchronize all the sensors' clocks. I don't need them to have the UTC time, but just the same tick counts after the server sends out start tick command. One tricky thing is that the server also connects directly to a sensor which might get the start-tick command earlier than others.

I am wondering whether there is some mature open source time synchronization algorithm for such scenario. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: Cristian's algorithm could solve this problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristian%27s_algorithm